# UnityVS error on importing?

Tags: unityvs

I have imported UnityVS 2.1 in my Unity 5.1.1f1 Personal.. and as soon as I import I get the following error.

> DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path
>   "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Unity Projects\Achievement
>   system\Library\UnityAssemblies\version.txt".
>   System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode,
>   FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean
>   anonymous, FileOptions options) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:292)
>   System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, FileMode mode,
>   FileAccess access, FileShare share) (wrapper
>   remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream:.ctor
>   (string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
>   System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor (System.String path, Boolean append,
>   System.Text.Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/StreamWriter.cs:124)
>   System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor (System.String path, Boolean append)
>   (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.StreamWriter:.ctor
>   (string,bool) System.IO.File.CreateText (System.String path) (at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/File.cs:159)
>   SyntaxTree.VisualStudio.Unity.Bridge.ProjectFilesGenerator.CreateVersionFile
>   (System.String[] assemblies)
>   SyntaxTree.VisualStudio.Unity.Bridge.ProjectFilesGenerator.DeployUnityAssemblies
>   (SyntaxTree.VisualStudio.Unity.Bridge.ProjectSystem.UnitySolution
>   solution)
>   SyntaxTree.VisualStudio.Unity.Bridge.ProjectFilesGenerator.GenerateProject
>   ()
>   SyntaxTree.VisualStudio.Unity.Bridge.Project+<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3
>   () UnityEditor.EditorApplication.Internal_CallUpdateFunctions () (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/editor/EditorApplicationBindings.gen.cs:264)

Can anyone tell me what is the problem?
I am using VS2015 community edition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok I have solved the problem... it seems like the UnityVS didnt create the folder structure as follows by itself

\Library\UnityAssemblies\version.txt

So I created it manually by creating the UnityAssemblies folder and a blank text file named version.txt inside it... and bam it worked perfectly..
Stupid UnityVS... had me worrying for 1 hour.

Answer (score 2):

This  happens when your project has no scripts  and wasnt started at least 1 time, only then that folder and file  is created

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: @MHakvoort: Actually, this is the correct answer. I looked at the higher-voted answer and thought, "Why should I be creating this version.txt file manually?" Then I saw this answer and realized it explained the actual problem: a bug where you get this error when there are no scripts in the project. I added one script to my project and tried again, and no errors this time. (I never ran into this in my usual projects because they already have scripts in them, but this was a test project with no scripts yet.)